# How to get the total ítems in MySQL in join

Tags: sql, mysql

i have 3 tables in MySQL.

Table: Ad

```
+-------------------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+

| Field                                     | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |

+-------------------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Ad_Id                                     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| User_Id                                   | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| Location_Id                               | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| Ad_Date                                   | timestamp    | NO   | MUL | current_timestamp() |                |
| Ad_Title                                  | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| Ad_Content                                | mediumtext   | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| Ad_Deleted                                | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
+-------------------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Table: State

```
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| State_Id             | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Country_Id           | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| State_Name           | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table: Location

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Location_Id   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| State_Id      | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Location_Name | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have this QUERY:

```
SELECT Anuncios.Ad_Id, Estado.State_Name, Municipio.Location_Name 
FROM Ad AS Anuncios JOIN Location AS Municipio 
ON Anuncios.Location_Id = Municipio.Location_Id 
JOIN State AS Estado ON Municipio.State_Id = Estado.State_Id 
WHERE Anuncios.Ad_Deleted = 0 AND Anuncios.User_Id = 600005;
```

My result is:

```
+---------+------------+-------------------------------+

| Ad_Id   | State_Name | Location_Name                 |
+---------+------------+-------------------------------+
|  2 | Jalisco    | Guadalajara                        |
|  2 | Jalisco    | Tlaquepaque                        |
|  2 | Jalisco    | Tonal?                             |
|  2 | Jalisco    | Guadalajara                        |
|  2 | Jalisco    | Zapopan                            |
|  2 | Jalisco    | Guadalajara                        |
|  2 | Jalisco    | El Salto                           |
|  2 | Jalisco    | Tlaquepaque                        |
|  2 | Jalisco    | Guadalajara                        |
|  2 | Jalisco    | Chapala                            |
|  2 | Jalisco    | Cocula                             |
|  2 | Jalisco    | Tonal?                             |
|  2 | Jalisco    | Tlaquepaque                        |
|  2 | Jalisco    | Zapopan                            |
|  2 | Jalisco    | Guadalajara                        |
.....
+---------+------------+-------------------------------+
```

But i don't need this, i just need the count about Location_Name (Municipio), for example:

```
Guadalajara 48
Zapopan 10
Tlaquepaque 7
....
```

How to get this result? (I change the User_Id and Ad_Id for the post)

Thank you, i new in MySQL:}

Comment: Have you tried, I dunno, using the `count()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(*)` query

```sql
SELECT
  m.Location_Name,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Ad AS a
JOIN Location AS Municipio ON a.Location_Id = m.Location_Id 
WHERE a.Ad_Deleted = 0
  AND a.User_Id = 600005
GROUP BY
  m.Locaton_Id,
  m.Location_Name;
```